# How to make Google Analytics API request with dimension: pageLocations and metrics: averageSessionDuration and newUsers?

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am trying to make the following dimensions and metrics using the Google Analytics API:

Dimension: pageLocations
Metric: averageSessionDuration
Metric: newUsers
However, I am getting an error message saying that the requested combination of dimensions and metrics is not supported.

I get next error:
`Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="InvalidArgument", Detail="Please remove pageLocation to make the request compatible. The request's dimensions & metrics are incompatible. To learn more, see https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/")`

Currently I'm using .NET library Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta Version 2.0.0-beta03. So, it's GA4 Api (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1).

I have checked the Dimensions & Metrics Explorer (https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/) and confirmed that this combination of dimensions and metrics is not available.
However, I can create an exploration using this combination of dimensions and metrics in the Google Analytics Exploration interface.

Is it possible to get these dimensions and metrics using the Google Analytics API? Or I should wait and this option will be added to API latter?

I will be glad to get all these data by .NET library, but if I have a chance to get this data by direct REST API request or some other technology, I would try to do that.
I would like to perform this action daily, but I don't want to manually download CSV file from Google Analytics Exploration and import it in my system.

I tried to access through .NET library and get InvalidArgument error and I check Dimensions & Metrics Explorer (https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/).
Therefore I believe straightforward solution to this issue is currently unavailable, but may be I can find some work around to get these values may be from other available metrics.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a combination of dimensions and metrics is not available, it means that it is a conflict.
Instead you may use dimensions `pagePath` and `hostname` together to create what you need:

`pagePath`: Represents the URL path of the page. This is exclusive of the domain. For instance, for the URL **https://example.com/products/shoes**, the `pagePath` would be **/products/shoes**.

`hostname`: This represents the domain name of the site. For the URL **https://example.com/products/shoes**, the hostname would be **example.com**.

These two combined would give you the complete URL. However, ensure that they are compatible with the metrics you're trying to fetch, if you want more metrics that haven't mentioned here.